# How do I get Webstorm 9 to work with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, webstorm

JetBrains has released an early access program version of Webstorm that supports Meteor debugging.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP

I've gotten it to run with my configuration (MONGO_URL, --settings, etc.), but haven't gotten Webstorm to stop on breakpoints yet.

What is the process by which I get Webstorm with Meteor support to stop on breakpoints?

Note this is about Webstorm *9*, not 7 or 8.  Webstorm 9 was released only a few days ago, so NO, there is not another question about this.  This is unique to the latest Webstorm version 9.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging Meteor app you should create a new 'Meteor' run configuration in WebStorm:
[image]

The setting 'MONGO_URL' can be passed over 'Environment variables' field in the configuration.

Unfortunately, the latest WebStorm 9 EAP has a bug [WEB-13260](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13260) so you cannot pass '--settings' option to Meteor. In the next EAP you can use 'Program arguments' field in the configuration.

Comment: I did that.  I know how to configure.  It's not stopping on my breakpoints though.  I get it to run in the debug console and I get really excited because Meteor debugging has always been challenging, and then I create breakpoints, and then my code runs, and nothing happens.

Comment: Do you sure that you start debug session?

Comment: Ok, it looks like it is working after trying again.  I have no idea if/what anything changed.  It seems as confusing as server-side debugging was prior to this release.  The extra tab opens up